# Dynamic minimum X axis value in scatter plot in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, x-axis

I have a scatter plot in Power BI. The bubbles get cutoff for the minimum values.

I want to create a Measure that multiplies the minimum value by 1.1 and use it as the new minimum value of the axis.

My scatter plot is connected to a coupe of slicers filtering the data:

Y axis:
Var Inv = Calculate(DIVIDE(SUM('Inv'[TY Inv]),SUM(Inv[LY Inv]) ,0)-1,FILTER('DailySales',DailySales[Like Date] ))

X axis
Var Sales = IFERROR(DailySales[TY Sales]/DailySales[LY Sales]-1,blank())

Thank you in advance..

Comment: No I think you should multiply by 0.9 or others smaller than 1. You can change the number untill all bubbles show. The maximum can be multiplied by 1.1 or others bigger than 1.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. My problems is not knowing how to write the measure, I can experiment with the numbers  later

Comment: You should let us know your scatter structure/table/have slicer or not. Every situation is different. There is no common measure calcultion for this.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I just updated my original post.

Comment: Should also know your slicers as minimum calculation should be changed by these slicers. Share pbix file is the most clearest way.